# How would one get an Exchange Rate between two currencies in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, currency-exchange-rates

I am trying to write an SQL query that would get the exchange rate for say Sterling to Euro.

I have tried the SQL below:

```
SELECT CurrencyCode,ExchangeRate FROM Currency
WHERE CurrencyCode='GBP';
```

I was expecting to get a list of two columns, currency name and exchange rates for sterling,
but something is not right; any ideas?

So...

```
SELECT ExchangeRate FROM Currency WHERE CurrencyCode = 'EUR';
```

This would return a single column for all of the rates for EUR against other currencies.

Comment: Please show the table schemas, and sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you don't have an intermediate `ExchangeRates` table, so you're using a base currency instead, if the base currency is GBP, the query you want is:

```
SELECT ExchangeRate FROM Currency WHERE CurrencyCode = 'EUR';
```

Here's [a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb915/2).

Comment: Can you give me an example of how one would get the rate between Sterling (base) and Euro (target).

Comment: @DavidCunningham That's actually the example I gave. Or do you mean that you have *multiple* base currencies in your table?

Comment: Yes sorry I have multiple base currencies

Comment: Ok, so presumably you have another column saying which `CurrencyCode` each `CurrencyCode` references? The query would be something like `SELECT ExchangeRate FROM Currency WHERE CurrencyCode = 'EUR' and BaseCurrency = 'GBP';`. If you still can't get this working, please edit the demo SQLFiddle I posted to include your actual schema and some data; and post the link in a comment.